# System.Xml C# как сделать необязательное для сериализации поле

Tags: c#, xml

Допустим у меня есть класс User, в классе User есть string? поле Country.
При сериализации файла создаётся

```xml
<User>
   <Country xsi:nil="true" />
</User>
```

Как сделать так чтобы данное поле не сериализовывалось,но при этом человек мог бы написать

```xml
<User>
   <Country>America</Country>
</User>
```

и это могло бы десериализоваться

Comment: поменять на `string`

Comment: пробовал уже...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам нужно только десериализовывать, но никогда не сериализовывать, то добавьте в свой класс метод

```
[XmlElement("Country")]
public string Country { get; set; }

[Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public bool ShouldSerializeCountry() => false;
```

Тогда он никогда не появится при сериализации, но заполнится при десериализации.
Для того, чтобы свойство сериализовалось, если оно не пустое, проверяйте в этом методе Country на null

```
[Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public bool ShouldSerializeCountry() => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Country);
```

Comment: Я пишу в файл это,сохраняю его,и загружаю файл,и Country уже нет
```xml
   <User>
      <Name>Paul</Name>
      <Age>14</Age>
   <Country>Russia</Country>
    </User>
```
```xml
   <User>
      <Name>Paul</Name>
      <Age>14</Age>
    </User>
```

Comment: Поправил код для работы с сериализацией, там должно быть `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Country);`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй у себя в классе User пометить это поле следующим атрибутом:

```
public class User
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
    public string Country{ get; set; }

    //// ....
}
```

Comment: ```xml
 <user>
    <Country xsi:nil="true" />
  </user>
```